# TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got <class 'function'>

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
logistic_model = LogisticRegression()
logistic_model.fit(X_train, y_train)


y_pred = none
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred) 
print (accuracy)
```

What should I put in the `y_pred = none` area? Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: `y_pred` is not the problem.  It's likely that `y_test` is a function instead of a list.  How did you define `y_test`?

Comment: Try `y_pred = logistic_model.predict(X_test)`

Comment: @MohilPatel The question was how are you setting `y_test`, not `y_pred`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would split your data in train and test, below an example using iris:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

X, y = make_classification()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

We can fit the model like you did:

```
logistic_model = LogisticRegression()
logistic_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Get the prediction on test set and score with actual value:

```
y_pred = logistic_model.predict(X_test)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```